# Prevent Johnny-Cache from invalidating whitelisted table caches when related, blacklisted tables are updated

Tags: django

In my Django app I have a set of infrequently-updated models which I'm caching using [johnny-cache](http://pythonhosted.org/johnny-cache/index.html), and another, frequently updated model (called `Page`) for which I've implemented a separate caching regime.

Several of the whitelisted models have foreign key relations to `Page`.  I know which of the whitelisted model caches should be invalidated when `Page` is updated, so I have implemented a set of signal handlers to explicitly invalidate caches after particular operations are performed on `Page`.

However, I have noticed that **johnny-cache** is automatically invalidating any model cache with a foreign-key relation to `Page` after every update operation.  This method (in `johhny.cache`) seems to be the problem:

```
def invalidate(self, instance, **kwargs):
    if self._patched:
        table = resolve_table(instance)
        if not disallowed_table(table):
            self.keyhandler.invalidate_table(table)

        tables = set()
        tables.add(table)

        try:
             instance._meta._related_objects_cache
        except AttributeError:
             instance._meta._fill_related_objects_cache()

        for obj in instance._meta._related_objects_cache.keys():
            obj_table = obj.model._meta.db_table
            if obj_table not in tables:
                tables.add(obj_table)
                if not disallowed_table(obj_table):
                    self.keyhandler.invalidate_table(obj_table)
```

The final section loops through all the tables that are related to the table being updated and calls `self.keyhandler.invalidate_table(obj_table)` on any that are whitelisted.

Is there any configuration that I can use which tells johnny-cache to ignore all changes to non-whitelisted tables?  Or do I have to do change the function like this:

```
         ...
         if not disallowed_table(table):
            self.keyhandler.invalidate_table(table)
         else:
            return
         ...
```

Which seems effective but ugly?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at caching solutions, which has more granular cache invalidation like [cacheops](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops) or [cache-machine](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine).